# fetch oldest date for content and check second table for same data

Tags: mysql

As part of a project i am working on, i have been working on a site where users are able to go and add/ edit content on different pages.

Currently, when someone adds a content section to a page, it gets added to the 'content' table with a date modified column, and a unique contentID column. However, when someone goes and edits this entry, i take the information for that ContentID in the 'content' table, and create a new entry in the 'changehist' table with this information(to track change history for the content entries). after that, I then update the content table with the new content and the date it was edited.

My Content table contains the following columns:
`ContentID, Heading, Content, DateModified, UserID`

And the ChangeHist table contains the following:
`HistID, ContentID, Heading, Content, DateModified, UserID`

What i have been asked to do is have a section that shows recently added content (in the past 3 weeks), but not recently updated content (content added a year ago, but updated last week). I currently am using the following query to do this:

```
SELECT content.* 
FROM content 
WHERE 
   (NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT 1 
      FROM changehist 
      WHERE  changehist.ContentID = content.ContentID)) 
AND content.DateModified > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK 
ORDER BY content.DateModified DESC
```

My issue here is that if content is added 3 hours ago, and was edited 2 hours ago, with my current query, the entry does not show up in the MYSQL results.

Is there a way to get this information in a single query, or do i have to use two separate queries, one on each table, and merge the two results together in php?

Comment: How would you do it with two queries? As far as I understand your question, your result is exactly what you've been asked to do. You want content, that was recently added but not recently updated. Content, that was added 3 hours ago and edited 2 hours ago, is recently updated, so it is correct to not show it.

Comment: If you want to show content, that was created in the past 3 weeks, you need to describe your tables because I think it is not possible with your information. You have `DateModified` with the date when it was created / updated last time and a list of changes. How can you know, when the content was created after it was updated?

Comment: @ThomasSablik if i had to do it in 2 queries,id have to get the contentID and `min(changehist.DateModified) as 'OldDate'` from the changehist table where 'OldDate' is from the past three weeks. Then Id have to search the contentID table as abouve, and maybe include filtering where the content id was the same as the results from changehist. Because i am giving a preview of the content on the webpage, i dont want to show the actual historic page content from chagehist. If that makes any sense....

Comment: Do you save the date of creation in `changehist`? `content.DateModified` is redundant. You should remove it. I would even say the whole `content` table is redundant. You can use `changehist` for everything.

Comment: When a content is first created is it saved in the changehist too?

Comment: @ThomasSablik essentially, yes. when a content entry gets modified, my code essentally takes everything from that ContentID in the content table, and creates a new entry in changehist with that information. therefore, the oldest entry in the changehist table for that specific ContentID could be considered the date of creation, and that would be determined by the 'DateModified' column in that table.

Comment: @cdaiga no it is not. it is only saved to the changehist table when it gets edited.

Comment: @ThomasSablik i could definitely see how it can appear the whole content table is redundant, considering it only holds the most recent version of each content entry. In some cases, it makes my sql queries simpler. Other cases like this, way more difficult. Also, i have modified my question with more information about the tables, and a little better description of how they are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a condition to get all the newly inserted.

```
SELECT 
    A.*
FROM 
    (SELECT ContentID, Heading, Content, DateModified, UserID
    FROM Content
    WHERE DateModified > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ContentID, Heading, Content, DateModified, UserID
    FROM ContentHist 
    WHERE DateModified > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK) A
ORDER BY A.UserID, A.ContentID, A.DateModified DESC;
```